# How can I get a single part of the expression in a group?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have an expression in LaTeX and I want to remove some things, I just want to keep a part, which is specified in a group.
But only remove the part that is before, and not the final part.

I tried separating it in 2 groups, being the first group the one that interests me to preserve, but even so the part that should remain in the second group remains in the second one.

Python

```
>>> import re
>>> a='\n{\\small{ Sean $x,y∈R$  y  evaluemos las potencias de  $(x+y)$:\n\n$(x+y)^0=1=1\n(x+y)^1=(x+y)=x+y\n\n(x+y)^2=(x+y)·(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2\n\n(x+y)^3=(x+y)·(x+y)^2=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3\n\n(x+y)^4=(x+y)·(x+y)^3=\nx^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4\n\n(x+y)^5=(x+y)·(x+y)^4=\nx^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$\n  }}'
>>> patron=re.compile(r'\n\{*\\small\{(?P<texto>.*)\}*', re.S)
>>> patron.findall(a)
[' Sean $x,y∈R$  y  evaluemos las potencias de  $(x+y)$:\n\n$(x+y)^0=1=1\n(x+y)^1=(x+y)=x+y\n\n(x+y)^2=(x+y)·(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2\n\n(x+y)^3=(x+y)·(x+y)^2=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3\n\n(x+y)^4=(x+y)·(x+y)^3=\nx^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4\n\n(x+y)^5=(x+y)·(x+y)^4=\nx^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$\n  }}']
```

I tried:

```
>>> patron=re.compile(r'\n\{*\\small\{(?P<texto>.*)(?P<llave>\}*)', re.S)
>>> patron.findall(a)
[(' Sean $x,y∈R$  y  evaluemos las potencias de  $(x+y)$:\n\n$(x+y)^0=1=1\n(x+y)^1=(x+y)=x+y\n\n(x+y)^2=(x+y)·(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2\n\n(x+y)^3=(x+y)·(x+y)^2=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3\n\n(x+y)^4=(x+y)·(x+y)^3=\nx^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4\n\n(x+y)^5=(x+y)·(x+y)^4=\nx^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$\n  }}', '')]
```

In this case, I was hoping to get '}}' in the second element of the tuple.

And I want to get:

```
[' Sean $x,y∈R$  y  evaluemos las potencias de  $(x+y)$:\n\n$(x+y)^0=1=1\n(x+y)^1=(x+y)=x+y\n\n(x+y)^2=(x+y)·(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2\n\n(x+y)^3=(x+y)·(x+y)^2=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3\n\n(x+y)^4=(x+y)·(x+y)^3=\nx^4+4x^3y+6x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4\n\n(x+y)^5=(x+y)·(x+y)^4=\nx^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$\n  ']
```

I mean, I want to remove '\n{\small{' from the beginning and '}}' from the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.*` inside your selecting group is matching the two `}` at the end, and since you have `*` after `}` outside, it's happy to let them be matched inside the selecting group and have none after.

I have two suggested solutions, depending on your full requirements:

- You can force the matching group to end on a character other than `}` with `[^}]:

  `patron=re.compile(r'\n\{*\\small\{(?P<texto>.*[^}])\}*', re.S)`

  this will work if your string always ends on those `}`, but not if anything follows them.
- if you know there are no `}` in the part to keep, make `.*` non-greedy (using `.*?`) and ask for 1 or more `}` at the end instead of zero or more, using `\}+`:

  `patron=re.compile(r'\n\{*\\small\{(?P<texto>.*?)\}+', re.S)`